# WFS Request Layer (GML) with Filter

Tags: geoserver, wfs, gml

Is there a solution to request the GML layer from Geoserver with filter like using `bbox`:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0
&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=50&
bbox=-74.0104611,40.70758763,-74.00153046439813,40.719885123828675
```

The result will be specific filtering the bounding box (lat/lon), based on `bbox` parameter that user entered.

**The Result:**

```xml
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.census.gov http://127.0.0.1:8080
 /geoserver/tiger/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&
 typeName=tiger%3Apoi http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
  /schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <tiger:poi fid="poi.4">
            <tiger:the_geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                  <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" 
                   ">-74.00857344,40.71194565</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>
            </tiger:the_geom>
            <tiger:NAME>lox</tiger:NAME>
            <tiger:THUMBNAIL>pics/22037884-Ti.jpg</tiger:THUMBNAIL>
            <tiger:MAINPAGE>pics/22037884-L.jpg</tiger:MAINPAGE>
         </tiger:poi>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**The problem now, I want to filter the data based on the `<tiger:NAME>lox</tiger:NAME>`, 
already tried with entered the `tiger:NAME=lox` as a parameter when request, the result just same like when enter no parameter. Is there a solution for this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Filter Encoding with Spatial Filter within WFS-Request](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Filter-Encoding-with-Spatial-Filter-within-WFS-Request-td4230814.html) and [Geoserver Filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html). I found that there is a parameter named `filter` and the value can enter like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0
&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=2
&filter=<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>NAME</PropertyName>
<Literal>lox</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a [filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html) - try something like:

```xml
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">
    <wfs:PropertyName>topp:STATE_NAME</wfs:PropertyName>
    <wfs:PropertyName>topp:PERSONS</wfs:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:And>
        <ogc:BBOX>
          <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
          <gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
             <gml:lowerCorner>-75.102613 40.212597</gml:lowerCorner>
             <gml:upperCorner>-72.361859 41.512517</gml:upperCorner>
          </gml:Envelope>
        </ogc:BBOX>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>topp:STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>Pennsylvania</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
   </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually already know about that, but what I'm currently didn't know is what is the parameter for the filter thing. I added an answer for that based on my research on [OSGeo](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/)